# Position absolute element to grow more than it's relative parent

Tags: css, sass

I have a span inside a button that has a position as relative.

```
.button-class {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: blue;
}

.span-class {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
 max-width: 120px; 
 margin-left: -20px; // This will be calculated using JS. Shoudl be (width of span-class / 2)
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
}

<button class="button-class">
 Button Text
 <span class="span-class">Span class text. More text.</span>
</button>
```

The span is aligned to the top of the button.

What should happen is the span-class width should grow according to it content until it reaches the max-width of 120px and then break into new lines. But since the parent is set to relative, it's taking up only the parent's width of 50px.

How do I make the position absolute element fit it's content instead of limit it's width to the parent?

The reason why I'm asking is **I do not want to use a fixed width** on the position absolute element.

[Link to the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/vj8zmc5b/)

Comment: Basically *you can't*. The span will collapse unless a width is applied to it as the text will wrap. If you stop the text from wrapping it will overflow when the max-width is exceeded.

Comment: As you can't to that, here is a workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/vj8zmc5b/12/

Comment: what ever your requirement may be. is setting span tag inside a button element a proper way of coding?

Comment: @divine Hi. The span is actually a tooltip that gets added inside the parent be it a button or any other html element. So the tooltip will be positioned to the center of it's parent all the time. Is it still wrong to do it like that?

Comment: @divine I followed this - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: @user3607282 good approach. it would've been better if you had mentioned  in your question that you are trying to implement a tooltip